# getting VBA to Append txt from bottom to top

Tags: vba, append, reverse

I would like to append a text (.txt) file backwards is this possible?

By backwards I mean writing text from bottom to top rather then the standards top to bottom.

Why because the txt file I want to compile is read so that items at the top of the list are given priority to those at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any other way than to create a new file whenver you want to insert data at the top and then delete/rename the old one and rename the new file to the new one.

Comment: Yeah this had crossed my mind too, its just a little hacky in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly your requirements BUT the easiest way in VBA is to 
1. Add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

```
Public Sub Reverse()
    Dim lReverseString As String
    Dim lFSO As FileSystemObject
    Set lFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    With lFSO.OpenTextFile("SourceName", ForReading)
        While Not .AtEndOfStream
            ' Note if you are looking to read a line at at a time use .ReadLine Instead of .Read
            lReverseString = .Read & lReverseString
        Wend
    End With
    ' now you have a string in reverse
    With lFSO.CreateTextFile("TargetName", True, False)
        .Write lReverseString
        .Close
    End With

End Sub
```

This is a basic form which should get you going.

Comment: Im going to check this code out, Im not after text being enterd backwards but that my last entries are at the top of the final txt file?

Comment: You can also use TextStream.ReadAll to read the whole file into a string variable.

Comment: Yeah the comment about .ReadLine should move a line at a time.

Answer (score 0):

How about an array? It would not be suitable with a very large file:

```
Dim fs As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim AllTextArray As Variant

''Late binding, no reference required
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
''ForReading=1
Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile("c:\docs\BookX.csv", 1)
AllTextArray = Split(ts.ReadAll, vbCrLf)

For i = UBound(AllTextArray) To 0 Step -1
    Debug.Print AllTextArray(i)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just writing each paragraph or sentence in the reverse order than it appears:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim currentDocument As Document
    Set currentDocument = ActiveDocument

    Dim sourceDocument As Document
    Set sourceDocument = Documents.Add("c:\words.txt")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = sourceDocument.Paragraphs.Count To 1 Step -1
        currentDocument.Range.InsertAfter sourceDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text
        DoEvents
    Next

    sourceDocument.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```